# Issue with uploading file inputs with multiple names

Tags: php, file-upload

I have several file input fields with a common name and a unique name for each file input .The unique name is for some validation purposes.

```
<input name="file12 ftr_file_uploads[]" class="multi_files file " type="file">
<input name="file10 ftr_file_uploads[]" class="multi_files file " type="file">
<input name="file10 ftr_file_uploads[]" class="multi_files file " type="file">
...............
```

When trying to upload files in PHP form submit,
the content of $_FILES is as following.

```
    array(2) { 
   ["file1_ftr_file_uploads"]=> array(5)
        { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Jellyfish.jpg" } 
        ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpx7iId2" } 
        ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } 
        ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(775702) } }
  ["file2_ftr_file_uploads"]=> array(5) 
        { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Penguins.jpg" } 
        ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpN6QWoD" } 
        ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } 
        ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(777835) } } 
  }
```

The array key name changed to the concatenated names of the file input field.I need the names to be `ftr_file_uploads` rather than `fileIDnumber_ftr_file_uploads`.

I have done like the following.

```
foreach($_FILES as $keyval=>$value)
    {
          $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'] = $_FILES[$keyval]; //removed 
           $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'][] mentioned in the answer 
           unset($_FILES[$keyval]);
    }
```

When i am using like this,I am getting the result like this.

```
    array(1) {
  ["ftr_file_uploads"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Lighthouse.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpLdslxb"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(561276)
    }
  }
}
```

I need the result like this.

```
 array(1) {
  ["ftr_file_uploads"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Hydrangeas.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "w.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpKMwmH1"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpwwHU9G"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(595284)
      [1]=>
      int(879394)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $name => $file) {
    $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'][] = $file;  // [] means add $file to $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'] array
    unset($_FILES[$name]); // remove element from $_FILES
}
```

Comment: I need another name to the input field for some validations.

Comment: So you can name it in this way name="ftr_file_uploads[0]", name="ftr_file_uploads[1]", name="ftr_file_uploads[2]"  etc. You will have different names in html and array in php

Comment: The response is different from the result I need.The result I got is array(1) { ["ftr_file_uploads"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(12) "Penguins.jpg" [2]=> string(9) "Koala.jpg" }
                                               ["type"]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [2]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ......

Comment: The result I need is the one which i mentioned in the question

Comment: `foreach($_FILES as $keyval=>$value)
        {
            $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'][] = $_FILES[$keyval];
            unset($_FILES[$keyval]);
        }`

Comment: I have used your answer,but the required result for me is not getting from it.Please can you help me

Comment: Do you try to get this result? https://snag.gy/FJdrv2.jpg  If yes, look this https://transfer.sh/LfId8/form.php

Comment: I have got the solution after working for several hours.Your answer is also perfect.If you put it as an answer I can accept it.So if future users check this,it can be helpful.